# CoreBluetooth bidirectional communication(tcp-similar approach)

Tags: ios, swift, tcp, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

What is the best way to provide bidirecational communication using CoreBluetooth framework?
I want to use BLE stack protocal as tcp-similar(only as a way for sending data) and then add upper layes: as tls, http, grpc etc.

We have 2 ways(I guess):

1. Via characteristics (but here we have restriction in 526 bytes strings and I'm not sure at all that we have complete bidirectional communication here)
   As example I have doubt about possibility to set communication via characteristics as simple tcp exchange.
2. Via L2CAP channels(in my mind it's just a 2 output/input streams for bidirectional communication) that complelty suits to tcp-similar approach.

Which way is the best and why? Maybe examples are present anywhere?

Comment: It depends on how much data you want to move, but it sounds like L2Cap would be appropriate.

Comment: @Paulw11 something like simple http encrypted requests, responses with information about user data.

Comment: But anyway much more then can characteristic contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "write without response" + "notifications" is almost the same in terms of performance compared to l2cap coc. In the end it is just a different header if you look at the raw BLE packets over the air that will be the difference (a few bytes might differ in the overhead, but nothing of importance if you have the LE Data Length extension enabled). One difference though is that you have the flow control mechanism for l2cap coc that you don't have for gatt.

My suggestion is to try both and pick the API that you like the most.

Comment: Could you explain more details about "flow control mechanism for l2cap", please? 
1.As I see I can use one characteristic as a "chat" between 2 devices. I mean from peripheral I did update for characteristic and got notification in central and from central using writeValue and got didReceiveWrite in peripheral.
2. With raw l2cap I can use just 2 kind of streams - output and input and using them in the same way.

Comment: With L2CAP CoC, if the sender writes faster than the receiver can consume, it will be aware of this and the write operation will block until the receiver is ready.

Comment: Interesting point, thanks. Via characteristic it has another behaviour right? And where did you find this information, because I read a lot of docs and didn't find such things
Then question can be closed.

Comment: You can read everything directly in the Bluetooth Core specification in the L2CAP and ATT/GATT chapters.